# New material dependencies not working on CoordinatorLayout preview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So, i have added all the android new material depency in order to work with BottomAppBar , but after I imported all and changed what the documentation suggest I cant even see the preview and when I compile I get the error that `test.runner` does not exists, and thats is maybe I removed the `support.test.runner` because it says that we don't need to mix support with material.

This is what I have done

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha01"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha01"

}
```

Styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I added to my AndroidManifest application tag this two suggeste lines by the compiler

```
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="settings"
```

I changed all the `AppCompat` from all my classes and replace them with the new AndroidX `AppCompat`

### Errors

> error: package android.support.test does not exist

this might be caused because I deleted support.test from my gradle since in the doc says we dont need to mix support with material.

And this error trying to preview `coordinatorLayout`

[image]

Any clue what it could be and how to solve all of this since I need to work with this material design as soon as posible.

Another thing, since it has AppCompat, I can run and see this design on my android 7 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android studio you have?
According here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
Android studio must be 3.2 or higher.
If your android studio is now 3.2 or higher there is an option under Refactor tab- "Migrate to AndroidX"  wait it to compile everything and AS will migrate your existing project to androidX which is the Material you are looking for.

If you may ask, here is my dependency for androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem just importing all material dependencies and not using any support ones